# My Jar launches using JDK7, but not using JDK1.8.0_101. Why not? Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-8, java-7

So, I'm trying to launch a jar application that I've built, but I'm encountering a very weird issue. When I tried to launch the application on the command line using `java -jar MyCookie.jar`, I received the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Now I know that this is a common error. It is basically telling me that the JVM can't find the main class (or that there is an issue with the main class). Naturally, the first things that I checked were:

A) Did I use the right FQCN, and spell it properly? YES.

B) Did I use MyCookie.jar instead of simply MyCookie in CMD, and main.java.MyCookie.mainClass in the manifest instead of main.java.MyCookie.mainClass.class? YES.

C) Is the desired class actually located in the JAR, or in the Class-Path? YES, The class is located in the main.java.MyCookie package, located within the MyCookie.jar.

After checking these things, I suspected something might be off with Java, especially as I have 4 different java installations on my machine (jre7, jre1.8.0_101, jdk1.7.0_80, jdk1.8.0_101), so I attempted to run the executable jar application on the command line with each different version.

Interestingly enough, I discovered that both the 1.8.0 jre and JDK produced the previously mentioned error, but that the application executed properly using both jre7 and jdk1.7.0_80. Not surprisingly `java -jar MyCookie.jar` wasn't working because my "java" was set to jdk1.8.0.

It may be a long-shot, but does anyone have any idea why my application may work in JSE7, but trigger a failure to load main class in 1.8.0?

I'm using Maven as a build tool, my main class is mainView, which looks like this:

```
package main.java.myCookie;

import main.java.gls.entities.Emp;
import main.java.gls.entities.JobStatus;
import main.java.gls.event.StringEventListener;
import main.java.gls.util.JustOneLock;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import main.java.myCookie.background.fetchEmpList;
import main.java.myCookie.background.fetchStatusList;
import main.java.myCookie.interfaces.Main;


    public class mainView
            extends javax.swing.JFrame
            implements Main
    {
        @PersistenceUnit
        final private EntityManagerFactory emFactory = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JobEntitiesPU");

        @PersistenceContext
        final private EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();

        Properties config = new Properties();

        ArrayList<EventListener> listenerList = new ArrayList<EventListener>();

        //set from property file in working directory
        String defaultPrinter;
        ArrayList<Integer> statusExceptionList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> statusLockedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ArrayList<JobStatus> adjustedStatusList = new ArrayList<JobStatus>();

        ArrayList<JobStatus> statusList = new ArrayList<JobStatus>();
        boolean statusListFetched = false;

        int defaultEmpId;
        Emp defaultEmp;
        Emp noEmp;
        ArrayList<Emp> empList = new ArrayList<Emp>();
        boolean empListFetched = false;

        PanelManager panelManager;

        public mainView()
        {
            lockTest();
            init();
        }

        private void lockTest()
        {
            JustOneLock jol = new JustOneLock("TimeClock");

            if ( jol.isAppActive() )
            {
                System.out.println("Instance of TimeClock is already Running");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        private void init()
        {
            MainSingleton.getInstance().setMain(this);

            this.openPropertiesFromFile();

            this.fetchEmpList();
            this.fetchStatusList();

            initComponents();

            panelManager = new PanelManager();

            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        private void openPropertiesFromFile()
        {
            System.out.println( "Current Working Directory: "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));

            //get properties file
            try
            {
                this.config.load(new FileInputStream( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\main.java.myCookie.properties"));

            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //get default user if it exists
            if ( config.containsKey("DEFAULT_USER") )
            {
                System.out.println( "DEFAULT_USER: "+config.getProperty("DEFAULT_USER") );

                this.defaultEmpId = Integer.parseInt( config.getProperty("DEFAULT_USER") );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "DEFAULT_USER: NOT FOUND (set to 1000)" );

                this.defaultEmpId = 1000;
            }

            //get default printer if it exists
            if ( config.containsKey("DEFAULT_PRINTER") )
            {
                System.out.println( "DEFAULT_PRINTER: "+config.getProperty("DEFAULT_PRINTER") );

                this.defaultPrinter =  config.getProperty("DEFAULT_PRINTER");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "DEFAULT_PRINTER: NOT FOUND" );

                this.defaultPrinter = "myPrinter";
            }

            //get status exceptions if it exists ( comma delineated )
            if ( config.containsKey("STATUS_EXCEPTIONS") )
            {
                System.out.println( "STATUS_EXCEPTIONS list found" );

                String[] rawSE = config.getProperty("STATUS_EXCEPTIONS").split(",");

                for ( String s : rawSE )
                {                
                    this.statusExceptionList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "STATUS_EXCEPTIONS list NOT found" );
            }

            //get locked status list if it exists ( coma delineated )
            if ( config.containsKey("STATUS_LOCKED") )
            {
                System.out.println( "STATUS_LOCKED list found" );

                String[] rawSL = config.getProperty("STATUS_LOCKED").split(",");

                for ( String s : rawSL )
                {
                    this.statusLockedList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "STATUS_LOCKED list NOT found" );
            }
        }

        private void fetchEmpList()
        {
            final fetchEmpList task = new fetchEmpList();
            task.addPropertyChangeListener
            (
                new PropertyChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt )
                    {
                        if ( "DONE".equals( evt.getNewValue().toString() ) )
                        {
                        try {
                            fetchEmpListDone(task.get());
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            task.execute();
        }

        private void fetchStatusList()
        {
            final fetchStatusList task = new fetchStatusList();
            task.addPropertyChangeListener
            (
                new PropertyChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt )
                    {
                        if ( "DONE".equals( evt.getNewValue().toString() ) )
                        {
                        try{
                            fetchStatusListDone( task.get() );
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
                        {
                            Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (ExecutionException ex)
                        {
                            Logger.getLogger(mainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            task.execute();
        }

        private void fetchEmpListDone( List<Emp> empList )
        {
            for( Emp e : empList )
            {
                //removes non-current employees
                if ( e.getEmpQuit() == null )
                {
                    this.empList.add(e);
                }
                //employee 1000: No Owner
                if ( e.getEmpNum() == 1000 )
                {
                    this.noEmp = e;
                }
                //sets default emp
                if ( e.getEmpNum() == this.defaultEmpId )
                {
                    this.defaultEmp = e;
                }
            }
            this.empListFetched = true;
        }

        private void fetchStatusListDone( List<JobStatus> statusList )
        {
            //only add status types that are not in the exception list
            for( JobStatus js : statusList )
            {
                this.statusList.add(js);

                if ( !this.statusExceptionList.contains(js.getId()) )
                {
                    this.adjustedStatusList.add(js);
                }
            }
            this.statusListFetched = true;
        }


        @Override
        public ArrayList<Integer> getStatusExceptionList()
        {
            return this.statusExceptionList;
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<JobStatus> getAdjustedStatusList()
        {
            return this.adjustedStatusList;
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<Integer> getStatusLockedList()
        {
            return this.statusLockedList;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDefaultPrinter()
        {
            return this.defaultPrinter;
        }

        @Override
        public Emp getDefaultEmp()
        {
            return this.defaultEmp;
        }

        @Override
        public Emp getNoEmp()
        {
            return this.noEmp;
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<Emp> getEmpList()
        {
            return this.empList;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean empListFetched()
        {
            return this.empListFetched;
        }

        @Override
        public List<JobStatus> getStatusList()
        {
            return this.statusList;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean statusListFetched()
        {
            return this.statusListFetched;
        }

        @Override
        public EntityManager getEM()
        {
            return this.em;
        }

        @Override
        public JComponent getParentContainer()
        {
            return this.mainPanel;
        }

        /** This method is called from within the constructor to
         * initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
         * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                        
        private void initComponents() {

            myCookieLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("myCookie");
            setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
            setResizable(false);
            getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

            myCookieLabel.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.disabledShadow"));
            myCookieLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
            myCookieLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            myCookieLabel.setText("Steve Pro");
            getContentPane().add(myCookieLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 640, 40));

            mainPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
            mainPanel.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
            getContentPane().add(mainPanel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 40, 640, 440));

            pack();
        }                       

        /**
        * @param args the command line arguments
        */
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        new mainView();
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel myCookieLabel;
        // End of variables declaration                   

        @Override
        public void addStringEventListener ( StringEventListener stringEventListener )
        {
            listenerList.add( stringEventListener );
        }

        @Override
        public void removeStringEventListener ( StringEventListener stringEventListener )
        {
            listenerList.remove( stringEventListener );
        }

        private void fireStringEvent( String string )
        {
            for ( EventListener l : listenerList )
            {
                if ( l instanceof StringEventListener )
                {
                    ((StringEventListener) l).stringEventFired(string);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.glsarchives</groupId>
    <artifactId>myCookie</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cecore</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>celib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ceplugins</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cereports</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cesession</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ceutils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dspace.xmlui.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>Concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>corbaidl</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.33-bin</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rascore</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.glsarchives</groupId>
            <artifactId>GLSLib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--Build Settings-->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>./src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>myCookie-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven-Dependency-Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven-Jar-Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>main.java.myCookie.mainView</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>myCookie-1.0</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                <!-- Copies resource files that can be accessed by the user (unpackaged resources), such as configuration and properties files to the installation directory -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-internal-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>          
                                        <resource>
                                                <includes>
                                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                                </includes>
                                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/external</directory>
                                                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/</targetPath>
                                        </resource>
                                </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/gls_desktop/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>main/java/gls_desktop/resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/gls_desktop/xml</directory>
                <targetPath>main/java/gls_desktop/xml</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/gls_desktop/jCalendar</directory>
                <targetPath>main/java/gls_desktop/jCalendar</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>Bundle.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/gls_desktop/jCalendar/images</directory>
                <targetPath>main/java/gls_desktop/jCalendar/images</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: bsnider
Class-Path: myCookie-1.0 lib/AbsoluteLayout-0.0.jar lib/cecore-0.0.jar
  lib/celib-0.0.jar lib/ceplugins-0.0.jar lib/cereports-0.0.jar lib/ce
 session-0.0.jar lib/ceutils-0.0.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib
 /Concurrent-0.0.jar lib/corbaidl-0.0.jar lib/eclipselink-2.5.2.jar li
 b/javax.persistence-0.0.jar lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar lib/mysql-connector-
 java-5.1.33-bin.jar lib/rascore-0.0.jar lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar lib/
 xml-apis-1.3.04.jar lib/xml-apis-0.0.jar lib/GLSLib-1.1.2-20170210.20
 0207-1.jar lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar lib/serialization.jar-0.0.jar lib
 /ebus405-0.0.jar lib/MetafileRenderer-0.0.jar lib/rasapp-0.0.jar lib/
 javax.mail-1.5.0.jar lib/activation-1.1.jar lib/org.eclipse.persisten
 ce.jpa-2.6.4.jar lib/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.6.4.jar lib/org.ec
 lipse.persistence.antlr-2.6.4.jar lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar lib/org.ec
 lipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.6.4.jar lib/org.eclipse.persistence.core
 -2.6.4.jar lib/imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar lib/awtextra-0.0.jar lib/ReportPr
 inter-0.0.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_101
Main-Class: main.java.myCookie.mainView
```

Comment: Try to put your main method in a class called 'Main', maybe Java 8 looks for a main class.

Comment: Please show your full class definition, the `pom.xml` and `MANIFEST` from the JAR

Comment: shouldn't the first entry in the manifest's Class-Path be "myCookie-1.0.jar". Currently it lacks the ".jar" ending, but I think maven likely generates a file ending in .jar. EDIT: but it doesn't make sense that the jar-file includes itself in the class path, so forget this comment.

Comment: As background, I meant to remove the myCookie entry entirely from the MF before I posted this question. It was there as a last ditch effort on my part to try and force the JVM to find the file inside of myCookie.jar, but unfortunately even pointing the JVM directly at the jar didn't help on Java 8 . It's not supposed to be there, I also tried adding the current directory to the Class-Path, and it didn't have any effect either.